# How to check if a particular string is in the innerhtml or not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-4

Let's assume here has a bunch of html like this:

```
<p>High noon</p>
<p>Highest rank!</p>
```

Using the querySelectorAll to get them all:

```
const pList = document.querySelectorAll("p");
```

**Then I want to know does the string "high" exist in each node in ES4.**

---

I tried both includes() and indexOf():

```
pList[0].innerHTML.includes("High")
pList[1].innerHTML.includes("High")
//or
pList[0].innerHTML.indexOf("High") !== -1
pList[1].innerHTML.indexOf("High") !== -1
```

But what I got are all true for all the nodes, rather than true for pList[0] and false for pList[1].

Comment: They both include the string 'High'

Comment: The string `thehighestpeakintheland` also includes the string "high".

Comment: `pList[1].innerHTML.indexOf("High") !== -1` returns true since it also contains the value "High" in "Highest". You need to use regex to search only for the word "high".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Solution based on regular expression.

```
var regex = /\bHigh\b/i;
regex.test(pList[0]);
regex.test(pList[1]);
//or
pList[0].innerHTML.search(regex) !== -1
pList[1].innerHTML.search(regex) !== -1
```

Comment: In the context of the question, `pList[0].innerHTML.search(regex)` - right?

Comment: `/\bhigh\b/i` would be better so it would be case insensitive (if needed).

Comment: Thanks for your attention.